# Extra branch published to Visual Studio Online Git repository not showing up on other workstation

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

We are just beginning to make use of Visual Studio Online services, and migrating our code base from internal TFS to VSO Git repositories.

I made use of Visual Studio 2013 in my office workstation to commit an initial version of a solution, to Master. Subsequently created a new branch "Release" and published it to VSO remote and seems fine too.

[image]

The Release branch is visible from VSO CODE control panel

[image]

However when I clone the repo from my home workstation, it only sees Master; Release is not visible.

[image]

Think I must be missing somewhere here; how do I effectively get to see (and pull) other branches in remote?

Comment: Does the branch list on your home workstation list remote branches or just local ones? Chances are it just lists local branches, and the "master" listed there is your local master branch that may or may not be identical to the remote branch with the same name. In this is the case you'll have to create a local tracking branch based on the remote release branch.

Comment: @MagnusBäck well i cloned over the repo and I see the Master branch code; so surely at least Visual Studio is aware of local and remote Master branches. Question is how to also clone over the Release branch? Why isn't Visual Studio able to gain awareness of other branches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 git, only Master branch listed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919907/visual-studio-2013-git-only-master-branch-listed)

Comment: When you clone a git, it will by default set up a local master branch that track's the remote's master branch. This isn't the case with other branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok I believe have found the answer; must manually create new local branch and track against remote branch.

Duplicate [Visual Studio 2013 git, only Master branch listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919907/visual-studio-2013-git-only-master-branch-listed)