# Branching Refresh in Visual Studio in TFS Online using Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio online as my source repository and have chosen git for source control.
I have created a new branch named as "Branch1" and published it in the server.

I want the fellow developer to get this branch in his visual studio and work with this. But the other developer is not getting this "Branch1" listed in his visual studio. How can the other developer refresh the list of branches available in the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your fellow developer [fetches commits from the team](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850436.aspx#fetch) first.

[image: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC698190.png]

Then he/she can create a local branch tracking that new remote branch.
See "[Visual Studio 2013 git, only Master branch listed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939697/6309)"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhz4k.png]

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from master branch to Branch1 would need at least 1 commit over it to be accessible in the team explorer menu of the visual studio.