# Visual Studio Git: Nothing happens when trying to view branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

In the alleged duplicate question, the person is able to open the Branches page and I am not.

Ok I am a total noob with git. This is the first time I have ever had to use it.

I am trying to join a project hosted in visual studio online using the built in git functionality in visual studio 2015.

I click join team project, enter the adress of the server, select the project and then press clone repository. The repository gets cloned successfully and I can access the code.

What I am accessing is the master branch, though. I need to be able to access another branch. So what I do is go to Team Explorer -> Press Branches....aand nothing happens. Ever. I could not find anything remotely related to my situation online, which I find really weird. I am able to access the branch fine through the web portal.

Also in source control explorer, I get a message saying that I am supposed to select the Team Foundation Server Source Control plugin even though visual studio automatically has selected Microsoft Git. I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

I have tried installing the git for windows tools, restarting visual studio etc. and nothing helped.

Really would appreciate some assistance.

[image]

As you can see, I have cloned the repository.

[image]

But when I attempt to click on Branches in the second screenshot, nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 git, only Master branch listed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919907/visual-studio-2013-git-only-master-branch-listed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I simply reset to default settings in Visual Studio.
Just go to Tools->Import Export Settings->Select Reset Settings and follow the wizard.